# Modify body in email_send hook

Tags: email

Is there an way to override the $_body in the email hook 'email_send'. I cant find a way to modify the raw body and not the $_final_body.

Rein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not. When building [Escort](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/escort), I had to manually break `$finalbody` into pieces using regular expressions so I could see what the email was actually made up of (note that it has already been mime-encoded at that point).